# mysqlimport: error in syntax

Tags: sql, mysql

i am trying to import a tab-delimited file into mysql. here is how i am doing it:

```
mysqlimport c:\file.txt
```

whats wrong with the syntax?

Comment: What error message do you get? Where does `mysqlimport` come from? It's not part of the default mysql binary I think.

Comment: Correction: Actually it is. What error message do you get, then?

Comment: error 1064, you have an error in your syntax (btw i am using windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
load data local infile 'c:/calibration.txt' into table employees.calibration fields terminated by '\t' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';
```